# Connected to mobile hotspot, no internet

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am connected to my phone's (OnePlus 5T) hotspot, but for some reason have no internet.

I've already tried disabling ipv6, but still - no internet.

Dns seems to be working fine because when I ping addresses like google, I can see the ip address of it.

When I ping something I don't get packets back

Comment: It may be a routing problem. Please, post `route -n` output in your original question.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli it seems like rebooting several times helped, idk why actually…

Comment: What is the connection to this site?   What OS & release are you talking about?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic